# How to pull to desktop files saved into "getFilesDir" on Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to pull files saved into the directory holding application files?

I created file from the application:

```
file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "locs_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+".log");
```

And I want to check, if it is correctly generated after some time. I want to do this non rooted on device.

When I want to go to app directory (package is sk.coplas.mitlocation.app) and try to list files, I have permission denied.

```
cd /data/data/sk.coplas.mitlocation.app
ls
opendir failed, Permission denied
```

When I try to pull this file using adb shell pull, I have Permission denied.

```
adb pull /data/data/sk.coplas.mitlocation.app/files/locs_1394631917783.log
failed to copy '/data/data/sk.coplas.mitlocation.app/files/locs_1394631917783.log' to './locs_1394631917783.log': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I found that it is possible to run "as application" if it is debuggable on device. Then I can change permissions on files and pull the files to desktop etc.

```
adb shell
run-as sk.coplas.mitlocation.app
```

Now I'm in root directory of my application

```
shell@mako:/data/data/sk.coplas.mitlocation.app $ ls
cache
files
lib
shared_prefs
```

Next I will go to files directory and list files and their permissions

```
shell@mako:/data/data/sk.coplas.mitlocation.app $ cd files
shell@mako:/data/data/sk.coplas.mitlocation.app/files $ ls -l
-rw-rw---- u0_a207  u0_a207       598 2014-03-12 14:46 locs_1394631917783.log
-rw-rw---- u0_a207  u0_a207       300 2014-03-12 14:46 locs_1394631973301.log
-rw-rw---- u0_a207  u0_a207       996 2014-03-12 14:48 locs_1394632002138.log
-rw-rw---- u0_a207  u0_a207        50 2014-03-12 14:56 locs_1394632574220.log
-rw-rw---- u0_a207  u0_a207        50 2014-03-12 14:56 locs_1394632602211.log
```

I will add read permission to everyone

```
10|shell@mako:/data/data/sk.coplas.mitlocation.app/files $ chmod 664 locs*     
shell@mako:/data/data/sk.coplas.mitlocation.app/files $ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- u0_a207  u0_a207       598 2014-03-12 14:46 locs_1394631917783.log
-rw-rw-r-- u0_a207  u0_a207       300 2014-03-12 14:46 locs_1394631973301.log
-rw-rw-r-- u0_a207  u0_a207       996 2014-03-12 14:48 locs_1394632002138.log
-rw-rw-r-- u0_a207  u0_a207        50 2014-03-12 14:56 locs_1394632574220.log
-rw-rw-r-- u0_a207  u0_a207        50 2014-03-12 14:56 locs_1394632602211.log
drw-rw---- u0_a207  u0_a207           2014-03-12 15:45 logs
```

And the from the terminal on desktop I will pull the file and everything works fine.

```
adb pull /data/data/sk.coplas.mitlocation.app/files/locs_1394631917783.log
5 KB/s (598 bytes in 0.102s)
```